# Is Spring @Component annotation used correctly?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, annotations

The purpose of this question is to find out if the codes are written with the right approach. Let's do CRUD operations on categories and posts in the blog website project. To keep the question short, I shared just create and update side.
(Technologies used in the project: spring-boot, mongodb)

Let's start to model `Category`:

```java
@Document("category")
public class Category{

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed(unique = true, background = true)
    private String name;

    @Indexed(unique = true, background = true)
    private String slug;

    // getter and setter
```

Abstract BaseController class and IController Interface is created for fundamental level save, delete and update operations. I shared below controller side:

```java
public interface IController<T>{
    @PostMapping("/save")
    ResponseEntity<BlogResponse> save(T object);
    @GetMapping(value = "/find-all")
    ResponseEntity<BlogResponse> findAll();
    @GetMapping(value = "/delete-all")
    ResponseEntity<BlogResponse> deleteAll();
}
```

```java
public abstract class BaseController<T extends MongoRepository<S,String>, S> implements IController<S> {
    @Autowired
    private T repository;

    @Autowired
    private BlogResponse blogResponse;

    @PostMapping(value = "/save", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<BlogResponse> save(S object) {
        try {
            S model = (S) repository.save(object);
            String modelName = object.getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase();
            blogResponse.setMessage(modelName + " is saved successfully").putData(modelName, object);
        } catch (DuplicateKeyException dke) {
            return new ResponseEntity<BlogResponse>(blogResponse.setMessage("This data is already existing!!!"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<BlogResponse>(blogResponse.setMessage(e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<BlogResponse>(blogResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    // delete, findAll and other controllers
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "category")
@RequestScope
public class CategoryController extends BaseController<ICategoryRepository, Category>{
    // More specific opretions like findSlug() can be write here.  
}
```

And finally BlogResponce component is shared below;

```java
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class BlogResponse{

    private String message;
    private Map<String, Object> data;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public BlogResponse setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
        return this;
    }

    public BlogResponse putData(String key, Object object){
        if(data == null)
            data = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        data.put(key,object);
        return this;
    }

    public Map<String,Object> getData(){
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BlogResponse{" +
                "message='" + message + '\'' +
                ", data=" + data +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Question:** I am new spring boot and I want to move forward by doing it right.  `BlogResponse` is set bean by using `@Component` annotation. This [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-stereotype-annotations) said that other annotations like @Controller, @Service are specializations of @Component for more specific use cases. So I think, I cant use them. `BlogResponse` is set prototype scope for create new object at each injection. Also it's life end after response because of `@RequestScope`. Are this annotations using correcty? Maybe there is more effective way or approach. You can remark about other roughness if it existing.

Comment: Don't... Why would that need to be a spring managed bean? Just create a new instance if you need one, same for `Category`. The `@RequestScope` you don't need either, just make it a singleton, unless it has state that is request specific, generally you don't. Is it wrong what you did, no it isn't it will work but you just don't need all of that and can make it simpler.

Comment: Thank a lot for your reply @M.Deinum. I understood. What conditions should I use `@Component` annotation or define bean?

Comment: Generally all your application/infrastructure beans. But not things like entities etc. that you store in your database, files etc.